# How do I access and modify a state from a non-Composable function?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, state, jetbrains-compose

I have this Composable function that holds multiple states:

```
@Composable
fun MyComponent() {
    var stringState by remember { mutableStateOf("foo") }
    var booleanState by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var integerState by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
}
```

I now want to modify these states from a non-composable function that requests an API every second or so and then update the state in my application depending on the response.

Note that this isn't the actual component but I need an answer applicable to not just one type.

I have read the docs and read the top SO answers but none of them really matched what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can your function return a `Flow` of API responses? Then you can use [`collectAsState()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#(kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow).collectAsState(kotlin.Any,kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext)):

```
@Composable
fun MyComponent(apiResponses: Flow<Response>) {
    val state by apiResponses.collectAsState(initial = ...)
}
```

Comment: Sadly not, I appreciate the (very fast) response though. I could try and refactor it to work like that, despite never really having made use of `Flow`s

Answer (score 0):

A solution you could look at is passing callbacks into your functions where you are able to reassign the variables. (since `by remember` constructors are just that).

Let's say you have a function `doStuffWithStringState()`, then you could just do something like this:

```
fun doStuff(onComplete: () -> Unit) {
 // do stuff here
 onComplete()
}
```

and when calling the function in the composable:

```
@Composable
fun MyComponent() {
    var stringState by remember { mutableStateOf("foo") }
    var booleanState by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var integerState by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

     LaunchedEffect(Unit){
         doStuff { stringState = "new state" }
     }
 }
}
```

If you have a more complex scenario, you could pass the current state as a parameter into the higher order function and then implement a switch in the callback:

```
enum class CustomState {State1, State2}

fun doStuff(onComplete: (CustomState) -> Unit) {
 // do stuff here
 val resultingState = determineState()
 onComplete(resultingState)
}
```

```
doStuff {
   when (it) {
      State1 -> { stringState = "state1" }
   }
}
```

But **i would not recommend this approach**, it looks a bit "unclean" in the compose philosophy. Your scenario very much sounds like it might need a refactor into a flow or livedata which is collected into a `StateFlow` inside the viewmodel and collected as state in the composable, just as you discussed in the other answer. State is *mostly* meant to be changed **either from a data source** (i.e. observing a data source) **or from user input**, i.e. a composable.

Which by the way, composables which modify state are intended to be used exactly this way. For example a `TextField` has the function parameter `onValueChange: (String) -> Unit` where you could set the variable from `remember` just like I described above.